# I have a point cloud with 4 points (a Polygon, all points in the same plane) in 3D space. How can I calculate the points between them?

Tags: 3d, geometry, polygon, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud with 4 points. This is how it looks in the file cloud.xyz:

```
334776.097 5691271.082 38.832
334780.919 5691274.153 39.100
334780.919 5691274.153 39.140
334776.097 5691271.082 39.028
```

The points are all in the same plane, it's a polygon. A polygon with 4 vertices.

How can I calculate points between these 4 vertices, so that I can add them to the point cloud.

For example:

X are the 4 vertices. O are the new calculated points

From this:

```
      X              X





X        X
```

To this:

```
      XOOOOOOOOOOOOOOX
     OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   OOOOOOOOOOOOO
  OOOOOOOOOOOO
 OOOOOOOOOOO
XOOOOOOOOX
```

I don't how to do this. I wanted to this with the Scan Line Fill Algorithm, but this algorithm is only for points in 2D, not 3D space.

EDIT: Guys, sorry. I also have polygons with 3, 5, 6 or more vertices in 3D space.

Comment: What do you mean with: "calculate points between these 4 vertices". As we are in real space there are infinitely many points between any two points. So, do you want something like a mesh refinement or what is the number of points you want to choose in this quadrilateral. Secondly, If you project the points onto a plane is it then a 2D problem, or why do you need 3D space?

Comment: The 4 points are on a plane, but this plane is in 3D space. I have many more of these 4 points planes/polygons.

With "calculate points between these 4 vertices" I mean just points between them. I doesn't matter with what distance between each point. I know there can be infinitely many points, but I just need a raster. The distance I can change later, that should not be the problem.

Comment: There is no raster for 3d case. What are you going to do with "all points"?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you want to distribute k points on a regular grid on the given (hopefully convex) quadrilateral Q(A,B,C,D) sucht the the points are given in CCW order. We form two normalised direction vectors pAD=D-A/|D-A| and pBC=C-B/|C-B|. Now using this two direction vectors we span the regular grid of size k=sqrt(k)*sqrt(k). Therefore we define start and endpoints for our grid segments: Let Si = A + i * pAD * |D-A|/sqrt(k) and Ei = B + i * pBC * |C-B|/sqrt(k) where we use ever integer in 0<=i<=sqrt(k) and compute for every such i the following:

For every tuple (Si,Ei) we compute again the normalised direction vector from S to E: pSEi = Ei-Si/|Ei-Si|. Now we can step through the i-th grid line segment and compute the sqrt(k) points for every such grid line: Like above we use: pij = Si + j * pSEi * |Ei-Si|/sqrt(k) where for j we use every integer in 0<=j<=sqrt(k).

This will give you k points in total which lie on a regular grid, as long as your quadrilateral Q is convex.

[image]

---

**EDIT**: This approach works also with three points. One uses as initial direction vectors pAB and pAC and then the points used in the triangle have to be scaled up in some sense, i.e., the i-th iteration away from point A would have i points in its row and we let i be in 0<=i<=2*sqrt(k) and j as well. Then we should end up with roughly k points in the end that are *ok* scaled in the triangle.

For more than 4 points it is the question how exact this grid has to be. One approach would be that we take an enclosing convex quadrilateral or even AABB Q. Then we use the approach described above but add a constant C and compute C*k points in the grid. Additionally we apply a point in polygon test for every point we add. **As long as the polygon in question has only a constant number of vertices:** This approach runs in O(k) time.

Comment: What if I have a polygon with 3, 5, 6 or more vertices? See my edit in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to implement a bi-linear interpolation. Mathematically this is done with the following vector equation

[image: math]

The four arbitrary points have coordinates

```
A = (x_A,y_A,z_A)
B = (x_B,y_B,z_B)
C = (x_C,y_C,z_C)
D = (x_D,y_D,z_D)
```

Then loop over two scalar values `t` and `s` ranging from `0` to `1` each with `n` and `m` intervals. Like `t = (i-1)/(n-1)` with `i=1..n`

The pseudo code below should do it

```
' Makes n×m points interpolated between A,B,C,D
' This will include the original points as
'   point(1,1) = A
'   point(n,1) = B
'   point(1,m) = C
'   point(n,m) = D

' Check if vectors AB and CD are pointing on the same direction (sense)
' Swap one of the vectors otherwise.
If InnerProduct(Vector(A,B),Vector(C,D))<0 Then
    Swap(C,D)
End If

' Define interpolation points based on a n×m grid
For i=1 to n
  t = (i-1.0)/(n-1.0)   ' NOT integer division
  T = Lerp(A,B,t)
  Y = Lerp(C,D,t)
  For j=1 to m
    s = (j-1.0)/(m-1.0)
    point(i,j) = Lerp(T,Y,s)
  Next j
Next i

Function Lerp(Q As Point,P as Point ,g as Float) As Point
    Lerp.x = (1-g)*Q.x + g*P.x
    Lerp.y = (1-g)*Q.y + g*P.y
    Lerp.z = (1-g)*Q.z + g*P.z
End Function

Function Vector(Q As Point,P as Point) As Point
    Vector.x = P.x - Q.x
    Vector.y = P.y - Q.y
    Vector.z = P.z - Q.z
End Function

Function InnerProduct(Q as Point, P as Point) as Float
    InnerProduct = Q.x*P.x+Q.y*P.y*Q.z*P.z
End Function
```

<sub>NOTE:
From arbitrary 4 points (not needed to be in-plane) pick two pairs that share the same sense. For example point *A*, *B*, *C*, and *D* if picked in pairs of *AB* and *CD* might have the wrong sense if the following is true `(B-A)·(D-C)<=0`. The `·` is the inner product, as *A*, *B*, *C* and *D* are vector (array) quantities. If the sense is wrong, then flip one the pairs. Take *AB* and *DC* then.</sub>

Comment: What if I have a polygon with 3, 5, 6 or more vertices? See my edit in my question.

Comment: Then you have a much bigger problem at hand. Ask [Mathematics.SE] if there is an established procedure. Essentially you are meshing a surface trimmed by a polygon. Or you are tesselating a polygon into triangles and filling in the triangles.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe I have to first transform the polygon to 2D space and then do the filling/rastering.